# Using multiple sql commands in a single method C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Scope :School Project
using: VS-2010, service based database
Experience Level: Beginner-2 months of basic coding only

General info: {Inventory,sales, purchases recording} windows (form) application System with service based database.

Problem: "In the Customer Order Info form' under method to "add order" i want to:

1. assign form input into variables
2. use the first reader to read product quantity, etc from the 'Inventory details table'
3. store data in variables
4. calculate new stock quantity and other need info
5. Sql to INSERT form inputs into 'order details table'
6. Sql to UPDATE new quantity into the 'Inventory details table'

   ```
     private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
       try
       {//
           //1. declare variables
           int OrderID;
           string CusName;
           string GoodsIssued = "";
           // for data entry into table
           string Entry1 = "";
           string Entry2 = "";
           string Entry3 = "";
           // for calulation of new stock level
           int ProductIDA = 0;
           int QuantityOut = 0;
           int OldQty = 0;
           int NewQty = 0;
           int ReorderLvl = 0;
           string ReorderState = "";

           //Boolean error = false;
           //2. get values from textboxes to variable
           OrderID = int.Parse(txtOrderID.Text);
           CusName = txtCustomerName.Text;
           if (rbYes.Checked == true)
           { GoodsIssued = "Yes"; }
           else if (rbNo.Checked == true)
           { GoodsIssued = "No"; }
           else { GoodsIssued = ""; } // further Error reporting possible
           /*due to complication we are compartmentalizing each iteam invoice*/
           Entry1 = txtOQty.Text + "-" + txtItemID.Text;
           Entry2 = txtOQty2.Text + "-" + txtItemID2.Text;
           Entry3 = txtOQty3.Text + "-" + txtItemID3.Text;

           //Sql instert data needs finish here
           //SQL sql Search data needs follow
           ProductIDA = int.Parse(txtItemID.Text);

           //
           //
           //

           string search = "SELECT * FROM tblInventoryDetails WHERE [Product ID] = " + ProductIDA + "";


           SqlCommand recall = new SqlCommand(search, con);
           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader reader = recall.ExecuteReader();


           while (reader.Read())// Readers need to be read using a loop!!
           {
               //string searchedId = reader[0].ToString();
               //ID  at loction 0 is ommited =can be included
               OldQty = Convert.ToInt32(reader[5]);
               ReorderLvl = Convert.ToInt32(reader[6]);
               ReorderState = reader[7].ToString();
           }
               ////////////////////////////////

           NewQty = OldQty - QuantityOut;
           if (NewQty >= ReorderLvl)   //verify syntax
           { ReorderState = "No"; }
           else { ReorderState = "Yes"; }
           con.Close();
           //3. create the query for entering new values into Order details table
           string insert = "INSERT INTO tblCustomerOrderDetails VALUES (" + OrderID + ", '" + CusName + "', '" + GoodsIssued + "', '" + Entry1 + "', '" + Entry2 + "', '" + Entry3 + "' )";
           string update = "UPDATE tblInventoryDetails SET Quantity= " + NewQty + ", [Re-Order Recommendation]='" + ReorderState + "' WHERE [Product ID] =" + ProductIDA;
           //4. Creating the sql command with query name and connection
           SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
           SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand(update, con);
           //5. Opening connection path
           con.Open();
           //6. Executing the command
           cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
           cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
           //7.Display message if these try is sucessful
           MessageBox.Show("Updated and Saved Sucessfully");
       }// close of try 
       catch (Exception ex)
       {   //8. display error message when its not sucessful
           MessageBox.Show("Error while saving" + ex);
       }// close of catch
       finally
       {  //9.Close the connection
           con.Close();
       }// close of finally
       //
   }
   ```

This is the order details form:
[OrderDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rka5.png)

Updated Question: 
The Update part of the query where I want the new values of Quantity and re-order recommendation to be updated in the InventoryDetails table does not seem to pass when run. Everything else seems to work fine. 
Can any one point out my mistake or tell me why the Update function seems to not run?

Observation:  is it because this is the second [ExecuteNonQuery()] for this connection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error returns?

Comment: I think it is because of the missing single quote around Entry3

Comment: Don't concatenate strings: use Parameters. Alaso: you should use a transaction around the 2 statements as they change state in 2 different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Insert-Statement, there are no quotation marks for Entry3.